# How to add new attribute in each json object of json array in java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to append  new key value pair in each json object of json array using java. I'm trying to add category field in the json array.

How to append the new field in each existing json object in a json array?

```
Current Format:
===============
{
    "records": [
        {
            "time": "2023-04-04T00:02:40.8303990Z",
            "ProviderName": "Service Control Manager",
            "EventId": 7036,
            "Level": 4
        },
        {
            "time": "2023-04-04T00:02:40.8303990Z",
            "ProviderName": "Service Control Manager",
            "EventId": 7037,
            "Level": 3
        }
]
}

Expected format: (Added Category field)
===============
{
    "records": [
        {
            "time": "2023-04-04T00:02:40.8303990Z",
            "ProviderName": "Service Control Manager",
            "EventId": 7036,
            "Level": 4,
            "category":"ABC"
        },
        {
            "time": "2023-04-04T00:02:40.8303990Z",
            "ProviderName": "Service Control Manager",
            "EventId": 7037,
            "Level": 3,
            "category":"ABC"
        }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

1. Deserialize json into a `Map` (e.g. using [jackson-utils](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/jackson-utils))
2. Add new field to reuired values
3. Serialize `Map` into a json (e.g. using [jackson-utils](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/jackson-utils))

I expect the map will look like `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>`  with one single key `"record"`.

---

```java
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path file = Paths.get("foo.json");
        addFieldToJson(file, "category", "ABC");
    }

    public static void addFieldToJson(Path file, String key, Object value) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = readJson(file, mapper);
        addField(map, key, value);
        writeJson(file, map, mapper);
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> readJson(Path file, ObjectMapper mapper) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file.toFile())) {
            MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructRawMapType(LinkedHashMap.class);
            return mapper.readValue(in, mapType);
        }
    }

    private static void writeJson(Path file, Map<String, Object> map, ObjectMapper mapper) throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.toFile())) {
            mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(out, map);
        }
    }

    private static void addField(Map<String, Object> map, String key, Object value) {
        Object records = map.get("records");

        if (records instanceof Iterable)
            for (Object record : (Iterable<Object>) records)
                if (record instanceof Map)
                    ((Map<String, Object>) record).put(key, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: If possible can u add a sample code snippet here ?